# Android enable/disable spinner touch listener at condition

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have an activity with a Spinner (with his own adapter) and another Adapter that manages the recycler view with its list . I'm trying to implement the following logic : when the list of the recycler is empty   the spinner should be enabled , otherwise it should be disabled until the list is empty again :

```
  sGames.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (pokemonCardsGridAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                v.performClick();
                v.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(PokemonTeambuilderEditorActivity.this, "The list is full", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However , this only works the first time , once the spinner gets disabled , it never receive any touch events again . How can I fix this?

Comment: If it's disabled, you won't have touch events. How is your list being filled/updated ?

Comment: I have a floating button that each time you press it , it adds a new element

Comment: Do you have an adapter for your list ? You should post your code so we can help more. The logic is update the spinner in your adapter. And your floating button call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Solved using registerAdapterDataObserver:

```
    pokemonCardsGridAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

        public void onChanged() {
            sGames.setEnabled(false);
        }

        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            if (pokemonCardsGridAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                sGames.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```